# Live wallpaper setwallpaper event listener issue

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, android-wallpaper

I am trying to figure out if there is any mechanism to detect when a user clicks on **Set Wallpaper** or presses **Back** in the preview screen or if they pressed the back button.
I have looked at the [Wallpaper Service Engine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html) and the only change I can make use of is to detect whether the user is   [in preview mode or not](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html#isPreview())

I am wondering if anyone else ran it to this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help:
Here is a simple wallpaper engine that logs few events

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        Log.d(TAG, "isPreview ... " + isPreview());
    }


@Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isVisible) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onVisibilityChanged .." + isVisible);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceRedrawNeeded(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceRedrawNeeded");  
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSurfaceDestroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alright just in case someone else runs into this issue. My solution was to:
start the wallpaper preview activity with result:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName
                        (MyActivity.this, MyWallpaperService.class));
                startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUESTCODE);
```

When the user clicks "Set Wallpaper" you will receive an

```
 Activity.RESULT_OK
```

When the users clicks  "Settings" you will receive

```
Activity.RESULT_CANCELED
```

Hope it helps